# Print Mysql queries produced by Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i want to get hold of Mysql queries produced by grails before or after executing.

```
 trainingList = PrivateTraining.findAll(query,parameter)
```

i want to print the complete mysql query which is executed by the above statement. 
is there anyway to print ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set this property in your `DataSource.groovy`:

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Example:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            /* ---------------------- */
            hibernate.show_sql = true
            /* ---------------------- */
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db"
            // ...
```

Comment: where it prints sql queries?

Comment: on setting hibernate.show_sql=true does it automatically prints sql queries in the console, stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your logging configuration:

```
debug 'org.hibernate'
```